# Can anyone explain detailed use of persistent.xml file in hibernate JPA project?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have read articles about hibernate -JPA on the internet but unable to understand how it used and how it is working in the background for hibernate. Also, need information about what should be the name of a persistent unit in persistent.xml and what is the use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly we use persistnce.xml / hibernate.cfg.xml to tell hibernate the following details

1. What Database you're using? so, that hibernate executes all the queries w.r.t that Database
2. Connecting to Database like Providing Username and password
3. The database name
4. Hibernate mapping files name and many more 
   [Go through this link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/java-persistence-xml-example)